# Automate mining on windows

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, mining, monerod-commands, windows

I am running mining on Windows 10 Pro in Microsoft Azure using MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit.

My process to mine currently is:

1. OPEN a MSYS2 terminal (lets call this MSYS2 A), navigate to appropriate directory and run *./monerod --offline*
2. OPEN another terminal of MSYS2 (lets call this MSYS2 B), navigate to appropriate directory and run ./monero-wallet-cli. Follow the instructions for loading a wallet. Enter start_mining [thread count]
3. Go back MSYS2 A, and run show_hr

My question:
Is there any way to automate the process of starting mining in MSYS2 windows e.g. something equivalent of having a .bat file in a CMD window in a start menu.

Bonus question: Is there any way to be alerted if mining fails and to automatically restart the service?

Comment: Scheduled Tasks pointing to the .bat or PowerShell script?  I'm sure PS can monitor running processes and alert and restart if they stop.  (I'm more a bash guy then PowerShell, so can't help much more then that.  But i'm positive its do-able)

Comment: its not .bat or PowerShell. Its MSYS2 which is the pre-requisite for mining monero

Comment: "Its MSYS2 which is the pre-requisite for mining monero" <= It's not.

Comment: MSYS2 is a pre-requisite for mining on windows. See https://github.com/monero-project/monero "On Windows:
Binaries for Windows are built on Windows using the MinGW toolchain within MSYS2 environment. The MSYS2 environment emulates a POSIX system. The toolchain runs within the environment and cross-compiles binaries that can run outside of the environment as a regular Windows application.

Preparing the build environment

Download and install the MSYS2 installer..."

Answer (score 1):

MSYS2 is needed to build on windows.
However, you can mine directly within the regular windows command line, that's what i am doing.
So you might be able to create a bat file to:

- Launch monerod
- Start mining to your address within monerod, or in another window with monero-wallet-cli.

Try something like:

```
cd <path/to/monerod/folder>
:loop
monerod.exe --start-mining <address> --mining-threads <threads>
goto loop
```

For more sophisticated stuffs, try using "expect" to start "show_hr".